# Accessing a selection or multiple selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview that consists of columns filename, date and size which I can load fine.  But when a selection is made I can't access the filename of the selected item.

I tried:

```
if (filelist.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    String text="";
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < filelist.SelectedItems.Count; x++)
        text += filelist.SelectedItems[x].Text;
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

But `filelist.SelectedItems[x].Text;` gives an error.

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no
>   extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: What's the type of your items?

Comment: your selected item is a `ListViewItem` that does not have a Text property.

Comment: In the SelectionChanged event just get the SelectedIndex and then use it to find the item you're looking for. eg, filelist[index].FileName

Answer (score 0):

You try to get property Text of an Object instance. First, you have to cast your SelectedItems to type you are expecting. For example, if your ItemsSource is:

```
var sourcelist = new List<YourBoundItemType>();
// add items to sourcelist 
filelist.ItemsSource = sourcelist ;
```

then:

```
var selectedItems = filelist.SelectedItems.OfType<YourBoundItemType>().ToList();
if (selectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    String text="";    
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < selectedItems.Count; x++)
        text += selectedItems[x].Text;
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

Note that your YourBoundItemType class have to contain Text property

Comment: I got it to work...I put my type in for YourBoundItemType then I accessed the Name property instead of Text and I got filenames.  Thank you.